# Hide navigation arrows depending on the active class of children inside li

Tags: jquery

I have run into a problem with a carousel which is not adding an `active` class to all of the `li` that he has. However, `active` class is added properly on the children of the `li`, depending on the left or right arrow click.

The code that i have works fine when the `li` has active class `active`, but is not working when the child of a `li` has a `active` class or not.

A demo for the working case, where `li` has a `active` class or not can be seen here
https://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/npamox58/22/

And in the next demo, is the html structure which i must have and where the jquery code is not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/npamox58/25/

I assume that existing code is looking for a second children inside each `li` so that creates the problem? Any solution to this issue where i must target the children from the `li` so i can show/hide the navigation arrows? Thanks.

```js
    $(function() {
      $('.prev-img').hide(); //initial run
      $('.tabs_nav li').on('triggerClassChange', function() {
        if ($(this).find('.thumbnail').first().hasClass('active')) {
          $('.prev-img').hide();
        } else {
          $('.prev-img').show();
        }
        if ($(this).find('.thumbnail').last().hasClass('active')) {
          $('.next-img').hide();
        } else {
          $('.next-img').show();
        }

      });

      $('.next-img').click(function() {
        var ref = $('.tabs_nav li').find('.thumbnail.active').get(0); // current item that has active class
        var refNext = $(ref).next(); //reference for the next item adjacent to the current .active item
        if (refNext.get(0) != undefined) { //make sure there is a item available
          $(refNext).addClass('active'); //add class to the next item
          $(ref).removeClass('active').trigger('triggerClassChange'); //remove class on current and trigger our custom event
        }

      });

      $('.prev-img').click(function() {
        var ref = $('.tabs_nav li').find('.thumbnail.active').get(0); // current item that has active class
        var refPrev = $(ref).prev(); //reference for the next item adjacent to the current .active item
        if (refPrev.get(0) != undefined) { //make sure there is a item available
          $(refPrev).addClass('active'); //add class to the next item
          $(ref).removeClass('active').trigger('triggerClassChange'); // remove class on current and trigger our custom event
        }
      });

    })
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.next-img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.prev-img {
  display: inline-block;
}
.tabs_nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs_nav">
  <li id='1'>
    <img src="imagge.png" alt="alt text" class="thumbnail active">
  </li>
  <li id='10'>
    <img src="imagge2.png" alt="alt text" class="thumbnail">
  </li>
  <li id='2'>
    <img src="imagge2.png" alt="alt text" class="thumbnail">
  </li>
  <li id='3'>
    <img src="imagge3.png" alt="alt text" class="thumbnail">
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="buttons">
  <div class="prev-img">left</div>
  <div class="next-img">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the reference of active class  using `$('.tabs_nav li img.active')` and then use `.next()` or `.prev()` to get reference of *next* or *prev* li and change class there.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.prev-img').hide(); //initial run
  $('.tabs_nav li').on('triggerClassChange', function() {
    var length = $('.tabs_nav li').length
    //check if the active class li index is 0
    if ($(".thumbnail.active").closest("li").index() == 0) {
      $('.prev-img').hide();
    } else {
      $('.prev-img').show();
    }
    //check if closest li index less then length
    if ($(".thumbnail.active").closest("li").index() == length - 1) {
      $('.next-img').hide();
    } else {
      $('.next-img').show();
    }

  });

  $('.next-img').click(function() {
    var ref = $('.tabs_nav li img.active'); //get active img reeference
    var refNext = $(ref).closest("li").next().find("img"); //find next img
    if (refNext.get(0) != undefined) {
      $(refNext).addClass('active');
      $(ref).removeClass('active').trigger('triggerClassChange');
    }

  });

  $('.prev-img').click(function() {
    var ref = $('.tabs_nav li img.active');
    var refPrev = $(ref).closest("li").prev().find("img");
    if (refPrev.get(0) != undefined) {
      $(refPrev).addClass('active');
      $(ref).removeClass('active').trigger('triggerClassChange');
    }
  });

})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.next-img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.prev-img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabs_nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs_nav">
  <li id='1'>
    <img src="imagge.png" alt="alt text" class="thumbnail active">
  </li>
  <li id='10'>
    <img src="imagge2.png" alt="alt text" class="thumbnail">
  </li>
  <li id='2'>
    <img src="imagge2.png" alt="alt text" class="thumbnail">
  </li>
  <li id='3'>
    <img src="imagge3.png" alt="alt text" class="thumbnail">
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="buttons">
  <div class="prev-img">left</div>
  <div class="next-img">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. It works perfect in your demo or a separated jsfiddle but unfortunately for me it doesn't work properly in the real site because on arrow click it jumps from 2 in 2 images. So it must have some kind of conflict with the jCarouselLite.